# Optional unexpectedly found nil and crash log info

Tags: ios, swift

I had this issue happening to me yesterday. I was dealing with a piece of production code that was crashing at a certain point with this crash info

```
0   Goga  0x00000001000b90b8 function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed> of Goga.NewViewController.emailButtonPressed (Goga.NewViewController)(ObjectiveC.UIButton) -> () (NewViewController.swift:0)
1   Goga  0x00000001000c0488 Goga.NewViewController.(emailButtonPressed (Goga.NewViewController) -> (ObjectiveC.UIButton) -> ()).(closure #2) (NewViewController.swift:872)
2   Goga  0x00000001000bd250 partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@in ObjectiveC.UIAlertAction!) -> (@out ()) to @callee_owned (@owned ObjectiveC.UIAlertAction!) -> (@unowned ()) (NewViewController.swift:0)
```

However, when I found the bug, after hours of trying to replicate the issue, any error message for it couldn't be found in the crash log. The bug was showing in XCode instead as:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

My question is, how to catch the nil-optional error in production code?

**Edit:**

Just to add a bit more of a perspective to the original problem, I found the issue in this sample code:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)  
cell.textLabel.text = "Hello" // CRASH if the cell is not visible in the view
```

I should have done this instead:

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
  cell.textLabel.text = "Hello" // Never get executed if cell is nil
}
```

Comment: @JayGajjar The question isn't seeking a specific solution but rather how to "catch" the error.

Comment: Debug your code and find actually at which line your code get crashed ! may be you forgot to initialize any of your variable.

Answer (score 5):

The way to "catch" the "nil-optional error" is simply by writing your code correctly.  Don't abuse forced unwrapping and forced down casting.

In this specific case, simply reading the crash details can give us some information:

```
1   Goga  0x00000001000c0488 Goga.NewViewController.(emailButtonPressed (Goga.NewViewController) -> (ObjectiveC.UIButton) -> ()).(closure #2) (NewViewController.swift:872)
```

Somewhere around line 872 of `NewViewController.swift`, you're force unwrapping something that's actually `nil` (and therefore cannot be unwrapped).

The solution is to go to line 872 of `NewViewController.swift`, find any occurrences of the exclamation point, determine whether it's a force-unwrapping operator or if it's a boolean operator... and if it's a force unwrapping operator, fix it using Swift's optional binding design patterns.

It could be that you're doing something like this:

```
let foo = bar!
```

Or perhaps somewhere `bar` is declared like this:

```
var bar: AnyObject!
```

Then it's never initialized (or at some point set to `nil`) and then because it's implicitly unwrapped, you're doing something like this:

```
let foo: AnyObject = bar
```

These can both lead to the error you're looking at.

Yes, implicitly unwrapped optionals and forced unwrapping can make things slightly more convenient when writing your code, but in the end, all it means is you run into these problems that you have to eventually track down later.  And there's no need to do so when Swift has plenty of tools to ensure we're being safe with `nil`.

Comment: Actually, that what I did. There was nothing wrong at that line. When I commented out the line (it wasn't important anyway) the same error started to happen in a later location in the same function which contains the line. You might think, I have the same problem in that other location; however, I assure you I was carefully handling that case for any nil values.

Comment: Instead of looking above/below that *line* of code, you need to look above/below that call in the stack.  Either something sends a potentially `nil` value to 872, or 872 sends a potentially `nil` value downward into something else that is either improperly allowing `nil` or improperly handling `nil`.  If you are able to recreate this crash, you can always us breakpoints or `println()` calls to track the code down to the source of the error.

Comment: I agree with you. Better safe than sorry

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with optionals you should be conditionally unwrapping them with an if statement.

```
var yourOptional: String?

if let unwrapped = yourOptional {
 // Do something with the variable
} else {
// It was nil
}
```

Comment: I totally get you here, but bugs happens, and if the value, let us say, is returned by a function call that in some rare case returns a nil, it wouldn't be too obvious to handle it this way.

Comment: It is the developer's responsibility to handle errors? If not the developer who, the user? That is it not easy to handle errors is irrelevant, that is part of the job. If you are explicitly unwrapping "!" when nil could in any way be returned don't, it is that simple.

Comment: @zaph I agree with you. But sometimes, our brain get scattered :)

Comment: Oh, what if the engineer of the bridge you probably drove across today had a "brain scatter" when he was designing it? But then we are neither engineers not professionals so I guess that's OK. ;-)

Comment: The whole point of an optional to is to inform the developer that this variable may at some point be nil. The compiler then forces you to unwrap this optional in which case you should be using the above approach to safely do so. I don't think it is matter of 'bugs happen' - there is a right way to deal with optionals, and this is it.